# What should a congregation do if it sins through ignorance? Leviticus and Numbers seem to give different commandments

Tags: contradiction

**Kill a young bull** (According to [Leviticus 4:13-21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=leviticus%204&version=ESV)):

**Kill a young bull and young goat** (According to [Numbers 15: 24-26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=numbers%2015&version=ESV))

How can these laws be reconciled?

Comment: Perhaps keep reading three more verses in Leviticus 4:22-24?

Comment: The contrast between the types of offerings(sin offering bullock vs burnt offering bullock + sin offering goat) may imply two different situations, the second where an individual was involved(cf. Num 15:27-29).

Answer (score 0):

Leviticus 4:13-21 and Numbers 15:24-26 describe two different situations.

A sin of omission is a sin committed because of neglecting to do what is right. They are good works left undone. While a sin of commission is typically observable and often more dramatic (e.g. adultery, stealing).

A burnt offering was both food for the god and a thanksgiving for the god's continued blessing. A sin offering was made to cover up the sin.

Leviticus 4:

> 13“ ‘If the whole Israelite community **sins** unintentionally and **does** what is forbidden in any of the Lord’s commands,

This was a sin of commission.

> even though the community is unaware of the matter, when they realize their guilt 14and the sin they committed becomes known, the assembly must bring a young **bull** as a **sin offering** and present it before the tent of meeting.

This was a sin offering to cover up the sin of commission.

On the other hand, Numbers 15:

> 22“ ‘Now if you as a community unintentionally **fail** to keep any of these commands the Lord gave Moses—

Unlike the case in Leviticus, this was a sin of omission.

> 24 and if this is done unintentionally without the community being aware of it, then the whole community is to offer a young **bull** for a **burnt offering**

Unlike the case in Leviticus, the bull was for a burnt offering.

> as an aroma pleasing to the Lord, along with its prescribed grain offering and drink offering, and a male **goat** for a **sin offering**.

Add a goat for a sin offering in this case of a sin of omission.

What should a congregation do if it unintentionally sins?

If it was a sin of commission, apply Leviticus 4:13.
If it was a sin of omission, apply Numbers 15:15.